# How to setup a file sharing service from ubuntu server over the net?

Tags: server, ssh, file-sharing, dropbox, filemanager

I have Ubuntu server edition that I ssh form on my mac and windows computers. I would like to know if there is any service I can install on my server that allows me to save and access my files from anywhere in the world ove the internet, similar to dropbox. I would prefer it if it is free.
Many thanks.

Comment: SSH is, in fact, such a service. Take a look at [howto configure ssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) for improved security.

Comment: if you already have ssh server enabled, you can use FilleZilla, Nautilus, Putty to browse files with your server user account

Answer (score 0):

It may be late but I just found [Owncloud](http://owncloud.org/) on [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2105155).